# How to know the root web memory size in a site colelction

Tags: 2007, powershell

I need to get the memory consumed by the root web of the site collection.

How could we know this using powershell scripting?

Any ideas, please share me.

Note- My farm is running on MOSS 2007.

Comment: If one of the answers solved the problem statet in your question, you should mark this answer as accepted answer to help future visitors.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following script for SP2010

```
Get-SPSite | select url, @{label=”Size in MB”;Expression={$_.usage.storage/1MB}} | Sort-Object -Descending -Property “Size in MB” | ConvertTo-Html -title "Site Collections sort by size" | Set-Content filename.html
```

This will output the size of all webs to a file

Try http://spusedspaceinfo.codeplex.com/ for MOSS

Comment: I think Anil wants to know how much memory (RAM) is being consumed by the root web app, not storage in the content database.

Comment: Hi Paddy, thanks for sharing the script. Yes, I wanted to know the storage consumed in content DB.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a powershell script for this. But do you have remote acces to the server? Then you can try to check it with sysinternals. There you can see, how much memoy the workerprocess takes.